# draw arc on preloaded images with javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm using a preloaded images array, which contains:

```
<img src='myimage.jpg'/>
```

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
var img = images[0];
ctx.drawImage(img,-centerX,-centerY, cwidth, cheight);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(10, 10, 10,0,Math.PI*2,false);
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 255)";
ctx.stroke();
```

Why is the draw arc in the above code not working?

Comment: We need more details to answer. Or can you add a fiddle ?

Comment: Try using `document.images` instead. Are you running this code `onload` or at some other time the image is loaded already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

**HTML Code:**

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600";">
```

**JS Code :**

```
 function startCanvas() {
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

        var image = new Image();

        image.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(image, 69, 50);
            //draw a circle
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(75, 75, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
        };

        image.src = 'download.jpg';
```

[fiddle here..](http://jsfiddle.net/Bharathi/Txm49/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I prepared a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bXX37/) and it works fine. If yours doesn't work after switching to `document.images`, try taking a peek at it. :)